How to separate the columns of this chart by groups "H01", "H02" and "H03"?
I want the groups to look like in the image in the same row. I would like the reader to be able to compare the bars by group and also between groups.
I'm trying to use facet_wrap but I get a graphic with nine panels. I just want to have three.

Can someone please help me?

Perhaps you could create a new 'grouping variable' from your data? E.g.
library(tidyverse)

# create a minimal reproducible example using the iris built-in dataset
iris_mre <- iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  mutate(H0_cat = paste0("H0", sample(1:3, n(), replace = TRUE),
                         " - ", sample(1:3, n(), replace = TRUE)))
iris_mre
#> # A tibble: 150 × 6
#> # Groups:   Species [3]
#>    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species H0_cat 
#>           <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>   <chr>  
#>  1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa  H02 - 1
#>  2          4.9         3            1.4         0.2 setosa  H01 - 2
#>  3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa  H01 - 2
#>  4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2 setosa  H02 - 1
#>  5          5           3.6          1.4         0.2 setosa  H01 - 2
#>  6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4 setosa  H01 - 1
#>  7          4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3 setosa  H03 - 3
#>  8          5           3.4          1.5         0.2 setosa  H02 - 2
#>  9          4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2 setosa  H01 - 1
#> 10          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1 setosa  H03 - 1
#> # ℹ 140 more rows

iris_mre %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = H0_cat, y = Sepal.Length, fill = Species)) +
  geom_col()


## add a new grouping variable based on the last digit of the H0_cat variable
iris_with_new_group_var <- iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  mutate(H0_cat = paste0("H0", sample(1:3, n(), replace = TRUE),
                         " - ", sample(1:3, n(), replace = TRUE))) %>%
  mutate(group = str_extract(H0_cat, ".$"))
iris_with_new_group_var
#> # A tibble: 150 × 7
#> # Groups:   Species [3]
#>    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species H0_cat  group
#>           <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>   <chr>   <chr>
#>  1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa  H01 - 3 3    
#>  2          4.9         3            1.4         0.2 setosa  H01 - 1 1    
#>  3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa  H02 - 2 2    
#>  4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2 setosa  H01 - 3 3    
#>  5          5           3.6          1.4         0.2 setosa  H03 - 2 2    
#>  6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4 setosa  H01 - 2 2    
#>  7          4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3 setosa  H02 - 2 2    
#>  8          5           3.4          1.5         0.2 setosa  H01 - 2 2    
#>  9          4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2 setosa  H02 - 2 2    
#> 10          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1 setosa  H01 - 1 1    
#> # ℹ 140 more rows

iris_with_new_group_var %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = H0_cat, y = Sepal.Length, fill = Species)) +
  geom_col() +
  facet_wrap(~group, scales = "free")


Created on 2024-06-26 with reprex v2.1.0
